# How to send a simple command to a Window's program on another machine

Tags: windows, remote-access

I have a program on a Windows machine that I VNC into.  It is a normal Window's program with a GUI written in Delphi.  After I VNC into the machine, I can select the program and hit Alt+S and then F to execute the command I want.

So, is there a simple way to send a command to this machine?

Answer (score 4):

If you VNC to the machine, you can look at Sysinternal's Psexec. It's a command line exe that allows you to send and capture output of remotely executed commands.

Comment: Yeah, it's great how you can capture the output of programs to your remote workstation.